# Switching keys of a dictionary without switching the values

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dictionary like below

```
myDict = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
```

and I'm trying to get this result

```
myDict = {"b": 1, "a": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4}
```

I tried running using

```
dictionary[new_key] = dictionary.pop(old_key)
```

But thats just deleting and appending a new key and value to the dictionary. It would result in:

```
myDict = {"b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "a": 2}
```

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: What's wrong with switching the values instead?

Comment: Is ordering important ?
Because `{"b": 1, "a": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4} == {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}  # True`

Comment: @0x0fba Forgot to mention that, yes, my final goal was to get the index of an item in the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I understand you aim to preserve the sequence.
Make first a new dictionary that maps the old keys to the new keys:

```
mapping = {"a": "b", "b": "a"}
```

Now you can generate the new structure

```
my_dict = {mapping.get(key, key): value for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

The `get` method here tries to map the key, but uses the key itself, if the key is not in the mapping.